# How do I keep my local version of files, without using .gitignore?

Tags: git, git-svn, gitignore

Don't want to change .gitignore because other people want the files in the repo. But I have my own copy that I want to use.

I edited `.git/info/exclude` and added the following:

```
/Gemfile
/Gemfile.lock
/config/database.yml
/spec/spec_helper.rb
```

This doesn't seem to do anything. `git status` still shows:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Gemfile
#       modified:   Gemfile.lock
#       modified:   config/database.yml
#       modified:   spec/spec_helper.rb
```

What is the best way to keep my local versions of files without using .gitignore?

Comment: Is this something you could use [Keyword Expansion](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) for?

Answer (score 7):

You could probably call `git update-index --assume-unchanged [file names]` or if there are a bunch of files, just do it to .gitignore and modify the ignore file as much as you'd like.

From [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) (emphasis mine):

> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell git when you change the working tree file.
>     ...
>   **This option can be also used as a coarse file-level mechanism to ignore uncommitted changes in tracked files (akin to what .gitignore does for untracked files)**.

Answer (score 4):

`.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` only apply to files that are *not* already in the repository. If the files are in the repository, you can't ask Git to ignore them.

What you could do is maintain these changes locally, either as a branch which you merge with incoming work on the master, or as a set of changes that you rebase on top of the master. Both of these are a bit inconvenient, however.

Answer (score 1):

I use a global ignore file on my machine which is also used - so this way you can have project based .gitignore files + your global settings which are local to your machine

eg I have this in in ~/.gitconfig

```
[core]
   excludesfile = /home/adrian/.gitignore
```

Comment: You cannot ask Git to ignore files that are already in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You've started all your files with a leading `/`.  I think if you were to remove that everything would work fine:

```
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
config/database.yml
spec/spec_helper.rb
```

Comment: I actually tried that before posting the question. Same result.

Comment: You cannot ask Git to ignore files that are already in the repository.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying with my previous comment.